# How to store c pointers in golang?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to store c pointers in `go`.

```
type perm struct{
    a *C.type1
    b *C.type2
}
```

The fields **a** and **b** in perm are pointers allocated by `C`.
But the cgo document https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/ says
**Go structs cannot embed fields with C types.**
It does not explain it further.
Does it mean that I can't store `C` pointers in `go` types?
If it does, how to store `C` pointers in `go`?
If not, what does that mean?

Comment: The fields in your example are not embedded fields; that code is valid.

Comment: What is embedded fields? @TimCooper

Comment: See: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types